# Linux friendly (.NET/Mono) browser object?

Tags: .net, browser, object, mono

A friend of mine (familiar with C# and .NET on Windows) has asked how to port some functionality to a Linux host. This functionality is based on a JSP web page that fetches some data from the host server and displays it in a banner on a page. His Win/C#/.NET code simply creates a browser object which loads the page and he then inspects the resulting object to extract the data.

I'm wondering what alternatives exist to duplicate this function on Ubuntu Linux. I'm not certain that the necessary libraries exist on this installation. I can assume that things like Perl and Python are ubiquitous, but I am not familiar with any libraries that include a browser object capable of executing javascript and exposing the results to another program.

Any suggestions that lead in this direction are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to port this to using [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) running on Mono.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that i understand your question, but do you mean [Web Browser](http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser) infrastructure?

Comment: Let me try and provide a better description. If I 'wget' the URL, I get javascript that does not include the information I want to scrape. I need to execute something that will fetch the javascript *and* execute it, putting the results in a format where I can extract some fields. Think along the lines if "wget | web-engine | output-parser"

Comment: I think that is possible with WebBrowser control.